# SAML2 and Form based login in same application with Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I'm trying to figure out how to support both form-based login for most users and saml2-based (spring security 5.4) login for some users in our application.

1. Users accessing app.exampleapp.com should be redirected to form login.
2. Users accessing sso.exampleapp.com should be redirected to SAML2 Identity Provider login.

I tried with a single Java configuration to handle both types but that did'nt work at all. So I'm trying with one configuration for form login and a separate configuration for saml2 login. But I can't get it to work either. One of them seems to take precedence over the other. If I disable the saml2 config I can login with form login and if I disable the form login config I can login using SSO/Keycloak. But I can't get both configs to work at the same time.

I have a `RequestMatcher` that matches on sub-domains in each security configuration.

Saml2 login config

```
http
    .requestMatcher(new SubdomainSecurityMatcher("sso"))
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/**")
    .authenticated()
    .and()
    .saml2Login(withDefaults())
```

Form login config

```
http
    .requestMatcher(new SubdomainSecurityMatcher("app"))
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/**")
    .authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
```

Do I need a custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint` to decide what login processing to perform?

I tried a lot of things but I'm not sure if or how it's supposed to work. Anyone managed to do something similar with the new SAML2 support in Spring Security 5.4?

Comment: iif you are using 2 configurations you need to define the `@Order` annotation on both and set an order. But you have not posted your full configuration so it is very hard to help you without the full security configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont put the redirectUrl to endpoint for saml that will create a session Token , and it can be implemented for basic auth too, it will give to you more flexibility to add every auth methods that you need in future ?

Comment: If you need some example I can write one for you

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your answer with some samples. Even if the author doesn't need it, that will make this answer more valuable to other readers with a similar problem in the future—which is what Stack Overflow is all about.

Answer (score -2):

Look [here](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/10/14/spring-security-saml-database-authentication), seems that `authenticationEntryPoint()` does the job